# bash + how to avoid specific messages in the log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, redhat

when I run the bash script on my Linux machine we get the following errors in my log ,

note - we set in the script:

```
exec > $log 2>&1 ,  (  in order to send all standard error/output to $log )
```

the errors messages:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

in order to filter this errors messages we try to set in the bash script that:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

**but without help**

after digging we found that  happened in some case for example when we perform ssh to remote machine and runs commands on remote machine VIA ssh

in order to avoid that we set TERM=xterm  in the bash script as the following:

```
ssh user@$remote_machine "TERM=xterm  /tmp/script.sh"
```

but it’s very not elegant solution and because my script use a lot of ssh and curl command then it’s not practical solution to set this on each SSH or curl etc

**so my big question is**

how to filter the message – **tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified** ?

so we not get these ugly message in my **$log** file

Comment: What are the contents of  `/tmp/script.sh`? One needs to know what it contains to identify why it causes the errors shown

Comment: its only example , usually we run commands as - ambari-server status , and many others , on the other case we run also curl commands and this happens also when we run curl in many approach

Comment: what I am asking is can we avoid some messaged by filter then before get them in the log ? or other good idea ?

Comment: Not sure if that information you gave helped. You say those errors come from a script you run. The right approach is to identify which lines cause those errors, not to avoid showing up.

Comment: let be focus on the log side , is it possible to filter the standard output/error before they go to the $log?  ( I mean to filter only the lines - tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Comment: While it is possible, it is not the best way to do it, what if you have another set of messages to suppress again? Adding separate filters is not recommended, but fixing the source of the problem IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out all `tput: No value` from logging:

```
exec > >(grep -v 'tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified' >$log) 2>&1
```

Comment: this syntax delete all line , maybe better to delete only the match strings - "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified"

Comment: exec | sed '/^tput: No value/d' > $log 2>&1    ( this stay the $log empty ! )

Comment: or exec  2>&1 | sed '/^tput: No value/d' >$log ( Iwe not get the $log file )

Comment: I've fixed that, now all the lines `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified` are filtered out.